# restrict access to standard button "new case" button on list view to particular profile

Tags: case

1.I have created a custom button which should be accessed by only 1 profile

2.I want restrict access to standard button "new case" button on list view to same profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need to hide a custom button and a standard list button from every profile but one. 
Unfortunately, salesforce doesn't provide any button level security directly. It provide page layout setting which can help us in this scenario. 
Follow the steps below you achieve the same :

1. Create 2 page layouts. Lets say Layout 1 and Layout 2.
2. Add these 2 button on Layout 1 and remove these 2 button from layout 2
3. Assign layout 1 to the profile you want to show these buttons to. And Assign layout 2 to rest of the profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the solution above does not work or is wrong for showing and hiding Buttons on **List Views**.
Currently salesforce does not have any feature that let you filter access based on profiles for List View Buttons.

The closest solution would be to

1. Create a custom lightning action .
2. Which opens a LWC page and shows the Account Record create form.
3. This LWC component would also check the profile
   and hide the form showing the message that you cannot
   create a account.